# django check values if they are empty

Tags: python, django

All fields have values, however, the app is redirected to the first if condition('Fields are empty!'). If I remove the condition the form is submitted. What am I missing here?
Any help is appreciated, thank you!

```
def application(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST['name']
        surname = request.POST['surname']
        email = request.POST['email']
        address = request.POST['address']
        city = request.POST['city']
        country = request.POST['country']
        zipcode = request.POST['zipcode']
        phone = request.POST['phone']
        if(name,surname,email,address,city,country,zipcode,phone == ""):
                return HttpResponse("<h3 style = 'background:#000;color:red; display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;width:100%;height:100%;font-family:lato;'>Fields are empty!!</h3>")
        else:
            application = Application(name = name, surname = surname, email = email, address = address, city = city, country = country, zipcode = zipcode, phone = phone)
            application.save()
            thename = name.capitalize()
            thesurname = surname.capitalize()

            )
            messages.success(request, 'Your request has been submitted, a representative will get back to you soon')
    return render(request, 'application.html')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function.

> Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the
> iterable is empty).

For example:

```
if not all([name,surname,email,address,city,country,zipcode,phone]):
    return HttpResponse("Fields are empty")
else:
    # your code
```